# Hide completed tasks, don't delete them

Tags: google-tasks

I have about 10 unfinished and 10 completed tasks in my Google Task list.

To mark a task as 'done', I click on a checkbox, this puts a <strike>strikethrough</strike> through the task. This still leaves the a cluttered list of tasks in my task list.

My other choice is to purge all tasks in my task list, using "Actions: Clear Completed Tasks". However, this deletes all of my tasks. I'd like to keep the task list around, for posterity.

Is there a way to hide my completed tasks from view, without deleting them?

Comment: For the record: This question is ancient and refers to an older, unused version of Google Tasks which is no longer relevant. I would prefer to delete this question, but don't have permission to do so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, marking a task as complete doesn't delete it, even after you choose "clear completed tasks". You can always view completed tasks. In the console view ( https://mail.google.com/tasks/a/yourdomain.com/canvas ) just choose the "Completed tasks" view. In Gmail or Gcal, you can choose "Actions/View Completed Tasks".

Comment: That's great. I had no idea that I could access tasks outside of Gmail/Gcal. This works for my work's Google Apps hosted account. It also works for my regular (non-hosted) gmail/gcal account. It's viewable at https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas

Answer (score 6):

I reckon this is an old post. The feature was very different back then (for example, checkboxes are no longer there, it is integrated with Google Calendar, etc.). However, the questions regarding whether you can hide task after completing it is still valid and this page was rank #1 when I searched the information on Google.

So, here's what I've got:

There is an option whether you wanto to "show completed tasks" or not in Google Calendar. Click the "Day" "Week" "Month" "Year" menu on your Google Calendar (picture is shown below, check the green arrow).

[image: show completed tasks in Google Calendar]

And then check or uncheck the menu "show completed tasks". (red arrow on the picture above).

Not quite intuitive I must say. I think the menu should be in setting. But for now, there is where you can find the menu.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to just hide tasks. Your options are either strike through or delete.

Comment: Not currently possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could just move them to their own list.

Comment: And this is what I did. I created a second list called "Completed Tasks", and I moved any completed tasks to that list. It's a kunky solution which requires many clicks, but it's what I'll do for now.

Comment: After this, @Herb Caudill pointed out that Google Tasks offers a "Completed Tasks" view. However, it's a little bit hidden when you are using Google Mail or Google Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous post if you clear completed tasks they are still viewable by selecting completed tasks in the canvas view.

After having tried 100's of productivity and GTD apps, google tasks in canvas view and set as my homepage is the best thing I've found to date, especially because my completed tasks are timestamped and available for review at the end of the month.

For anybody on a productivity trek who may be interested my lists are: Coordinate, Compose, Delegate, Follow up and Review. I find I don't need an inbox as to date I have always been able to put tasks directly into these lists. Hope it may be useful to someone!

Answer (score 0):

Clear completed tasks is NOT delete. It is a hide function.   In the same menu, choose  view completed tasks to see ALL past completed tasks.    The " Clear Completed Tasks"  is really mis-marked.

Comment: Maybe true but not really an answer to: "_Is there a way to hide my completed tasks from view, without deleting them?_". And in any case, not even an observation not mentioned before by others.

Answer (score 0):

There is one desktop app for Google Tasks from Google, https://tasksboard.app/.
Managing the tasks is very easy. Here is another useful piece of information about [Google Tasks](https://automate.io/blog/google-tasks-app-guide/).

Find or hide completed tasks:

- On your computer, go to Gmail.
- On the right, click Tasks Tasks.
- To see completed tasks, next to "Completed," click the Down arrow Drop
  down arrow.
- To hide, click the Up arrow Up arrow.

Comment: From their website: TasksBoard is not affiliated with Google in any way

Answer (score -2):

Clear Completed Tasks:
To clear or hide completed tasks from your task list, click “Actions” at the bottom of the “Tasks” window and select “Clear completed tasks” from the popup menu.[image]

Comment: This method was already mentioned within the question post as a non-solution.

Answer (score -2):

No there is no way. For "posterity" that would mean you'd have a never ending list of tasks taking up space and you're already limited to space with all your Google apps aggregated. If you want this, for example, to show you paid a credit card - you can copy the task and enter it on your calendar. That's what I do with my task list. I change the date of the task every month when it's completed and bump the date to the next month. Another example would be "8-1-2019 renew car registration". I'll renew it, copy it to my calendar as "renewed" then decide if the item is important enough to keep until the next time.